# ember.js simple-auth with django rest: No authenticator for factory "simple-auth-authenticator:django-rest-auth" could be found

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to get ember to work with ember-simple-auth (https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) and django-rest-auth (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-django-rest-auth) but looks like I'm missing something..

I keep getting

```
"Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: No authenticator for factory "simple-auth-authenticator:django-rest" could be found!" and I'm not sure what I'm missing.
```

Basically I followed this example https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth-example and replaced the authenticator with the django-rest-auth and added the initializer from the ember-cli-django-rest-auth docs.

Any ideas what I'm missing? also if there's any working example of ember-cli-django-rest-auth that would be great.

thanks!

EDIT:
added config from environment.js

```
ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000';
ENV.APP.API_NAMESPACE = 'chat/api';
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:django-rest',
    serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/',
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://localhost:8000'],
    store: 'simple-auth-session-store:ephemeral'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without seeing any code, but one thing i noticed is that it should be "django-rest" not "django-rest-auth". What does the relevant simple-auth section of your environment.js look like?

Comment: thanks brian, actually it was originally "django-rest", I was playing with that option and posted the error from when it was "django-rest-auth", one of my desperate attempts to make it work :) posted the config from environment.js.